# Pyqt two buttons connect to method to set text in label

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have two buttons and I would like to connect it to label to see text.

In __init__method i have:

```
self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.labeltext)
self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.labeltext)

def labeltext(self):
    if self.pushButton.clicked:
        self.label.setText('A')
    elif self.pushButton_2.clicked:
        self.label.setText('B')
```

The problem is, if I click button number two, it label text with "A", which is defined under Pushbutton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [sender()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#sender) method for this:

```
def labeltext(self):
    sender = self.sender()
    if sender is self.pushButton:
        self.label.setText('A')
    elif sender is self.pushButton_2:
        self.label.setText('B')
```

Comment: Thank you. For some reason I get aborted (disconnected) message in python ide

Answer (score 1):

If you use functools.partial, you can replace the connection lines as below. Also you can simplify labeltext function by adding a string parameter which is passed when the button is pushed.

```
def labeltext(self, text):
    self.label.setText(text)

self.pushButton.clicked.connect(partial(self.labeltext, 'A'))
self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(partial(self.labeltext, 'B'))
```

If you don't like functools.partial, you can also use lambda as follows:

```
self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(lambda: self.labeltext('B'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by using [`partial`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial).

Using `partial`, you will pass the text you want displayed in your `.connect()`.

```
qbtn1.clicked.connect(partial(self.labeltext, "A"))
qbtn2.clicked.connect(partial(self.labeltext, "B"))
```

You will also need to adjust the `labeltext` function signature to accept the text you wish to display.

```
def labeltext(self, text)
```

instead of the standard

```
def labeltext(self)
```

---

A full demo looks like this (with code borrowed from [zetcode](http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt4/firstprograms/) for the quick samples):

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from functools import partial

class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__() 
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):     
        self.lbl = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        qbtn1 = QtGui.QPushButton('Set "A"', self)
        qbtn2 = QtGui.QPushButton('Set "B"', self)

        self.lbl.move(20, 100)
        qbtn1.move(20,40)
        qbtn2.move(20,60)

        qbtn1.clicked.connect(partial(self.labeltext, "A"))
        qbtn2.clicked.connect(partial(self.labeltext, "B"))     
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 280, 170)
        self.setWindowTitle('Demo')
        self.show()

    def labeltext(self, text):      
        self.lbl.setText(text)
        self.lbl.adjustSize()       


def main(): 
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

Notice that the function we are calling `labeltext` now takes two parameters - `self` and `text`.

When the application first launches, the label is empty:

[image: First open]

The label will change when each button is clicked:

[image: Clicked A][image: Clicked B]